# JavaScript: is there a way to get returned values using Promise from a rate-limited function which got delayed

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I have a rate limiter function written like this

```js
function rateLimter(fn, wait) {
  const queue = []
  let isCalled = false

  const schedule = function () {
    const canSchedule = queue.length && !isCalled
    if (canSchedule) {
      isCalled = true
      queue.shift()()
      setTimeout(() => {
        isCalled = false
        schedule()
      }, wait)
    }
  }

  return function (...args) {
    queue.push(fn.bind(this, ...args))
    schedule()
  }
}
```

It works ok when we don't need the returned value or responses from the function provided to `rateLimiter`.

I am trying to rewrite this `rateLImiter` to give us the responses or returned value. I figured I can just pass a callback to get that response like this

```js
function rateLimter(fn, wait, getResponse) {
    const queue = []
    let isCalled = false
  
    const schedule = function () {
      const canSchedule = queue.length && !isCalled
      if (canSchedule) {
        isCalled = true
        getResponse(queue.shift()())
        setTimeout(() => {
          isCalled = false
          schedule()
        }, wait)
      }
    }
  
    return function (...args) {
      queue.push(fn.bind(this, ...args))
      schedule()
    }
  }
```

However I was trying to use `Promise` to get the value. Here is my attempt

```js
function rateLimter(fn, wait) {
  const queue = []
  let isCalled = false

  const schedule = function () {
    const canSchedule = queue.length && !isCalled
    if (canSchedule) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        isCalled = true
        resolve(queue.shift()())
        setTimeout(() => {
          isCalled = false
          schedule()
        }, wait)
      })
    }
  }

  return function (...args) {
    queue.push(fn.bind(this, ...args))
    return schedule()
  }
}
```

It only works for the first call but for any subsequent calls to the rate-limited function doesn't return `Promise` anymore. Can some give it a try? The exmaple I am testing against is

```js
const logMessageLimited = rateLimter2( async (msg, index) => {
  console.log(msg, index)
  return index + 10
}, 1000, getResponse)

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    logMessageLimited(`[Message Log] Action (${i}) rate limited.`, i).then(console.log) // should log out `10` , `11`, `12` 
}
```

Comment: What is `getResponse`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this does what you want. It's basically the same as your original approach except that we return a promise and additionally store the promise's `resolve` handler in the queue.

```js
function rateLimter(fn, wait) {
  const queue = []
  let isCalled = false

  const schedule = function () {
    const canSchedule = queue.length && !isCalled
    if (canSchedule) {
      isCalled = true
      const [fn, resolve] = queue.shift()
      resolve(fn())
      setTimeout(() => {
        isCalled = false
        schedule()
      }, wait)
    }
  }

  return function (...args) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      queue.push([fn.bind(this, ...args), resolve])
      schedule()
    })
  }
}

const logMessageLimited = rateLimter( async (msg, index) => {
  console.log(msg, index)
  return index + 10
}, 1000)

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    logMessageLimited(`[Message Log] Action (${i}) rate limited.`, i).then(console.log) // should log out `10` , `11`, `12` 
}
```

Your approach doesn't work because you are returning the promise from `schedule` but only if `canSchedule` is `true` (which will only be the case the first time the function is called (within the interval).

Comment: love your solution. It is briiliant!